# PHP Script always exceeds memory limit when adding to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, memory-limit

I've been going mental over this one. I'm sure it never used to do this, however I must've changed something so it did.

This is the `php` script in question:

```
<?php

echo <<<START
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Spotify Community Staff Tracker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/respond.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
START;

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);

require_once('config.php');

$posts = array();

$db = new mysqli($config['host'], $config['user'], $config['password'], $config['database']);

if ( ($result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `posts`')) != false)
{
    while ( ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) !== false)
    {
        if (@$_GET['idfilter'] && @$_GET['idfilter'] != $obj->board)
        {
            continue;
        }

        $posts[] = array('datetime' => $obj->datetime, 'subject' => $obj->subject, 'post_url' => $obj->post_link, 'user_url' => $obj->author_link, 'user' => $obj->author_name);
    }

    if (sizeof($posts) == 0)
    {
        if ($_GET['idfilter'])
            die("Filter caused zero result, or cron hasn't run.");
        die("Cron hasn't been run.");
    }

}
else
{
    die("An error occured.");
}

$lupdate = mysqli_fetch_object($db->query("SELECT * FROM `last_update`"));

echo <<<BOTTOM
<div id="right" class="fixed">
    <p id="lastupdate">Last Updated: {$lupdate->timestamp}</p>
    <p><form id="filter" action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a forum id to filter..." name="idfilter" />
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" id="submit" />
    </form>
            </p>
</div>
BOTTOM;

echo("\n<div id=\"posts\">");

foreach (array_reverse($posts) as $post)
{
    echo("\n<p><a class=\"postlink\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"{$post['post_url']}\">{$post['subject']}</a> - by <a class=\"suser\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"{$post['user_url']}\"><img src=\"http://spotify.i.lithium.com/html/rank_icons/spotify_icon_new.png\" alt=\"Spotify Staff\" />{$post['user']}</a> <span class=\"datetime\">on {$post['datetime']}</span>\n</p>");
}

echo("\n</div>");

echo <<<END
\n</body>
</html>
END;

?>
```

Whenever I run it I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 44 bytes) in <filepath>\index.php on line 36`

It's always the same error, - same allocation, same line. I've tried moving things around, I've tried using an array instead of an object, no use.

Any ideas as to *why* such a large amount of memory is trying to be used?

(There are around 400 rows in the database)

Comment: I suggest you make a small, self contained example that has the issue. With all the html etc that we don't need inside, it's too much work to  find out what your code is, and this is something you can easily do for yourself. see http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Nanne I was afraid a section of the code wouldn't make sense on its own. Noted for next time though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's this line that's causing you the problem:

```
while ( ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) !== false)
```

If you look at the documentation: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

mysqli_fetch_object returns the next row if there is one; or null if there isn't. So because you're doing a strict comparison, your loop will never end. To fix this, you can simple do:

```
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
```

And let PHP's type juggling convert the null at the end of the recordset to a boolean false.

Comment: Doh! I added that in because of Zend studio... Removed it and the error vanished. Something so simple...

Answer (score 1):

Try Increasing your memory-limit in php.ini or in this script use:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

Comment: I second this notion - in PHP.ini it wouldbe this: memory_limit = 256M

Comment: He's got an infinite loop in his code. How will adding more memory fix that?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't catch that right away.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: I think about 95% of the questions I see with an out of memory error are because there's an infinite loop in the code. There are just enough that aren't to keep me guessing....

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating work to PHP.

After your query, you are doing **while iterations through your results**, and storing **rows** in a PHP array. And, at the end of your script, you are **iterating** your array and put this into HTML output.

I think, that you cand do all with a single iteration, replacing your **foreach posts** by:

```
while ( ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) !== false)
{
    if (@$_GET['idfilter'] && @$_GET['idfilter'] != $obj->board)
    {
        continue;
    }

    echo("\n<p><a class=\"postlink\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"{$post['post_url']}\">{$post['subject']}</a> - by <a class=\"suser\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"{$post['user_url']}\"><img src=\"http://spotify.i.lithium.com/html/rank_icons/spotify_icon_new.png\" alt=\"Spotify Staff\" />{$post['user']}</a> <span class=\"datetime\">on {$post['datetime']}</span>\n</p>");
}
```